# Customize the appearance of citations in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, citing

One of the benefits with `natbib` is that it allows you to customize with simple commands in the preamble how you want your citations to appear, with respect to what symbols to use between multiple citations, etc. I have not been able to find anything similar in `biblatex`.

To be concrete, using the `authoryear` style in `biblatex` will make citations appear as this:

"See e.g. Smith (1983, pages 255 sqq.); Jones (2001, pages 112 sq.); Anderson (2004, page 85)."

In my field, however, this is not how citations normally look. They will rather look like this:

"See e.g. Smith (1983:255ff.), Jones (2001:112f.), Anderson (2004:85)."

Is there any way I can customize these options in the preamble with `biblatex`?

Comment: biblatex comes with a variety of styles which are described in the [biblatex documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex), plus there are some [more styles available on CTAN](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/). If that's not enoguh, you can [create new styles / customize existing ones](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806).

Comment: @matth I have looked in the biblatex documentation, but could not find anything about customizing these things. Creating/customizing new styles is yet far beyond my abilities. The advantage with ``natbib`` is that it is very easy for users like me who are not that savvy in LaTeX programming, and I was hoping something similar would be possible with ``biblatex``.

Comment: Could you add a MWE? When I use `biblatex` with `style=authoryear`, citations do not look as described in your text. In that example you can use `\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}` or `\addbibresource{xampl.bib}` as bibliography, both should be available in every TeX distribution. And do you know you can add pre-notes and post-notes to the cite command? For example like this `\cite[see e.g.][255ff]{bertram}`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon}

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}

\renewcommand*{\sqspace}{}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  sequens = {f\adddot},
  sequentes = {ff\adddot},
}

\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addcomma\space}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{Smi83,
  author = {Smith, S.},
  year = {1983},
  title = {Sierra},
}
@misc{Jon01,
  author = {Jones, J.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Juliet},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

See e.g. \textcites[255\psqq]{Smi83}[112\psq]{Jon01}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That looks great. Do I understand it correctly that I don't need to add the stuff from ``\usepackage{filecontents}`` to ``\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}`` - that's just for illustrative purposes?

Comment: @Sverre: That's for making my minimal example compile. :-)

Comment: Got it. Your solution worked beautifully.